# Nodejs,MongoDB - Query posts that have similar tags

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I have a lot of posts in a MongoDB Collection, which has an array of artists which is referenced to the Artists collection.

What I am trying to do is display similar posts on the singular post page, for instance "Posts you might also like:"

Performance is crucial to me, so the quickest way possible would be most beneficial.

Thanks!

(Im using Node.js and Mongoose)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a recommendation engine. It's a complex topic, specific to your app and is not something you can achieve by executing one simple query.